# help me find a light php/html/js IDE

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ide

ok ok i know SO is full of this kind of question,
but there's a catch:

here's what i need:

- a fast and light PHP/HTML/CSS/JS (jquery support ?) IDE
- Onestly i'm a PHP devolper AND a web designer so i need something good in both fields (syntax check is a must, web preview would be awesome)
- Here's the catch: No Overkill like Eclipse, NetBeans ecc... i'm working almost entirely at 5/10 days projects, i don't really have the time to put up such environments (projects, cvn...). I just need to open the (php,html,js,css) file, modify it and save it in the fastest possible way....
- No text-editors (notepad++), they're fine, but i'd like to try something "more"

I'm currently using Dreamweaver cs5 and i'm fine with it, but it's a little too CPU demanding for me...

Thanks !!

Edit: i'm on Windows 7

Comment: It might help to let people know what operating system you use, so that people can offer better advice.

Comment: Se these: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-ide/index.html

Comment: Why is Eclipse overkill and CS5 not? You don't need to set up all the extra stuff.

Comment: It's not free, but have you looked at something like http://www.e-texteditor.com?

Comment: eclipse forces you to create projects, workspaces ecc.. cs5 just let me open the file on the fly as a common text-editor...

Comment: test the demo of phpstorm http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ I'm not answering as I don't know if this qualifies as "fast & light". It surely is smart, auto-completes every technology you want and has several small bits of "intelligence" that improves your code workflow.

Comment: PHPstorm is very good. Although first load of a 'project' can be a little slow, but subsequent loads are fairly fast. I wouldn't say it's a great option if you were opening it up to edit just 1 file and then completely quitting the program afterwards though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) on both Windows and MAC and I love it.

Or try [pspad](http://www.pspad.com/)

Comment: hmm Komodo...seems good ! i'm gonna try it...thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Coda on OSX but since you're talking about Notepad++ I assume you're on Windows...
Anyway, could make you want to switch ;-) http://panic.com/coda/

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Comment: While you can set up projects yourself in PhpStorm etc, it will automatically convert a folder into a project if you choose File->Open Directory. If possible, don't quit the program completely as well, as it can be a little slow to "boot" the first time.

Answer (score 1):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) supports
[PHP](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PhpMode) and
[JavaScript](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EcmaScript) and pretty much everything. It pwns!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/). They are small and do not require high performance.

- [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.
- Some more details about [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) (free and open source), from the linked page:

  > With focused visual tools and preprocessor support, Brackets is a modern text editor that makes it easy to design in the browser. It's crafted from the ground up for web designers and front-end developers.
- Some more details about [Atom](https://atom.io/) (free and open source), from the linked page:

  > Atom is a text editor that's modern, approachable, yet hackable to the core—a tool you can customize to do anything but also use productively without ever touching a config file.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Tks. It done